# Reduce my functions

Tags: python

How do I reduce 2 functions that do the same thing? 
In fact it's a matter to add the array `score` with the array `score2`.

```
def printPoint1(name, point, score):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print("Name : " + name[i] + " Your score is of " + str(point[i]) + " : " + str(goal[i]) + " goals. ")
  score.append(point[i])

def printPoint2(name, point, score2):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print("Name : " + name[i] + " Your score is of " + str(point[i]) + " : " + str(goal[i]) + " goals. ")
  score2.append(point[i])
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what it is you are asking. What is currently not working in your code? Please edit your question to make it more clear what is currently failing.

Comment: You don't need the second one.  You're passing a list-like object via the score variable.  That can be any list.  These two functions are EXACTLY the same.  Just delete the second one and use the first one with whatever list-like object you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that the job of a function ! don't need to copy the code for each new variable to treat. 
if you define :

```
def printPoint1(name, point, score):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    print("Name : " + name[i] + " Your score is of " + str(point[i]) + " : " + str(goal[i]) + " goals. ")
  score.append(point[i])
```

then you can call your function as much as you want :

```
printPoint1(Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

with any different `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3` you just should respect the `type` (int, float, list, string, etc....) of each variable that you function will treat

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to not create two functions that do exactly the same thing. Just create one function and you can pass `score` or `score2`.